# Service Stack Handle Exceptions

Tags: c#, exception, servicestack

In project I working in is used service stack with next ovveriding of **HandleException** method of ServiceBase class:

```
    public abstract class BaseAggregationService<TRequest, TResponse> : ServiceBase<TRequest> 
    where TRequest : BaseAggregationRequest 
    where TResponse : BaseAggregationResponse
    {
         ....
         protected override object HandleException(TRequest request, Exception ex)
         {
             base.HandleException(request, ex);

             Logger.Error(request.Metadata, ex);

             var response = (TResponse) Activator.CreateInstance(typeof (TResponse), new Metadata());
             response.Exception = new AggregationException(ex);

             return response;
         }
    }
```

The native example of realization (from [github wiki](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Error-Handling)) is below.

```
    public class MyServiceBase<TRequest> : RestService<TRequest>
    {
        public override object HandleException(TRequest request, Exception exception)
        {
           //log your exceptions here
           ...
           //call default exception handler or prepare your own custom response with 
           return base.HandleException(request, exception);
           // or prepare new customer response with new HttpError(...)
        }
    }
```

My problem is I cant receive Exception field - it always null.Other changes in this method on responce received as expected.Should I do any additional configuration or I have not appopriate implementation?